# Heroku: Rails 5 ActiveCable configuration issue. Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, heroku, websocket, actioncable

I`ve been implementing a simple chat app with Rails 5 and ActiveCable. Locally this app works great. But when I try to test it on heroku, I get in JS console the following:

'Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing'

What I did:
I followed this [guide](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable).
I set the cable.yml

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://rediscloud:url_here
```

I set the URL in production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
    config.web_socket_server_url = "wss://my-app.herokuapp.com/cable"
```

I set the allowed hosts.

```
 config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins =
    ['https://my-app.herokuapp.com',
    'http://my-app.herokuapp.com']
```

But this doesn`t help. Any ideas why this error happens or how can I fix it?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the server selected as default.

The default server server was Thin. It was sending incorrect reply.

I`ve changed the server back to puma according to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#adding-puma-to-your-application%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00) guide and no code changes more needed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After Struggling a lot with the same issue we even started thinking to change the default server from `thin` to `Puma`.

But we finally got the answer to this :)

ActionCable does work w/ Thin now w/ a few extra configs:
In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'faye-websocket'
gem 'thin'
```

Create a `config/initializers/thin_action_cable.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.action_cable.use_faye = true
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter 'thin'
```

this link helps me to fix that issue.

[ActionCable not working with Thin #23696](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23696)